# Best way to share Github pull request templates between projects?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Github [recently announced](https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates) the addition of [pull request templates](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/). This is an awesome feature that has been heavily requested in the community for some time.

These templates are added by including a special file named `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` to the root of the project or within the `.github` directory. I have multiple projects for which I would like to use the same template. What is the best way to keep these templates in sync across projects?

(Git submodules are the only thing I can think of, but that seems pretty heavy-handed and complexity-prone for such a simple use case).

Comment: Not sure of any way to automate this, aside from something like a custom [probot](https://probot.github.io/) app

Answer (score 2):

Another *tricky* way might be creating a new organization and configuring [organization-wide templates](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-default-community-health-file).